# At which points is the function $f(z) = |z|^2$ complexly differentiable?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm try to solve this **question**:

*At which points is the function $f(z) = |z|^2$ complexly differentiable?*

My ***solution***:

let $z = x + yi$ then $z = x^2 + y^2$

Using Cauchy–Riemann equations we have $u(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$ and $v(x,y) = 0$
and
$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 2x, \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = 2y, \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = 0, \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = 0$$ 
Now we have simple system:

$$
\begin{cases} 2x = 0 \\ 2y = 0
\end{cases}
$$

And the obvious solitions:
$$
\begin{cases}  y = 0, x = 0
\end{cases}
$$
So function f complexly differentiable in point:
$z = 0$

Let's check it out. From defenition we have:
$$f'(0) = lim_{z \rightarrow 0}{\frac{f(z) - f(0)}{z}} = lim_{z \rightarrow 0}{\frac{z * \overline z}{z}} = 0$$

Comment: You'd better learn how to take partial derivatives. (Also, you have a typo: you should have $\partial v/\partial y$ ...)

Comment: Now? all right?

Comment: Much better. Except now it's just one point. (And you didn't correct the typo.)

Comment: Also, don't forget the C-R equations are a \emph{necessary} condition for complex differentiability, you have to explain why it is also sufficient in this case.

Comment: Bcpicao, now good? ted-shifrin am I forgot points?

Answer (score 1):

You might also make use of Wirtinger derivatives for a quicker approach:

$f(z)=\lvert z\rvert^{2}=z\bar z\Rightarrow\frac{\partial f}{\partial\bar{z}}=0\Leftrightarrow z=0$